# In vuetify.js, Specifying a router path as an attribute (<v-btn to="/path">) makes the button look like it's in "hover" state

Tags: vue-router, vuetify.js

I'm trying to add a router link to a button.

In the code below you can see I'm using 2 different methods:

### Code

```
<!-- Button 1 -->
<v-btn flat to='/'>home</v-btn>

<!-- Button 2 -->
<router-link to='/' tag='span' style='cursor:pointer;'>
  <v-btn flat>home</v-btn>
</router-link>
```

### Result

The first one (that uses to="" attribute) permanently looks like it's in hover state (the color is the same when you hover a button)

[image]

### Question

Is there a way to fix it? I like the first method, it's simpler, but why doesn't it look right?

And should I even use the first method, or the 2nd one is better?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depends what you want (but I presume you don't want button *highlighted* on any route), specify `active-class` as nothing.

```
<v-btn flat to='/' active-class>home</v-btn>
```

or, for home route you might want to use `exact` so button wont be highlighted on every page, but only at `/`.

```
<v-btn flat to='/' exact>home</v-btn>
```

[Here](https://router.vuejs.org/en/api/router-link.html) is more about why it happens, and [vuetify buttons api](https://vuetifyjs.com/components/buttons#api) which explains props.

Comment: One more question. Do you happen to know if the first method (just adding an attribute `to=""` in a button) doing exactly the same thing as when you're wrapping it in a tag `<routing-link>`  ?

Comment: @Un1, according to documentation, yes.